# How to retrieve data from BLE device in iOS?

Tags: swift, object, core-bluetooth

I would like to get data from BLE device which is offering two services and among them, one is offering  3 characteristics and another one is offering 2 characteristics.
Could you please explain how to retrieve data from device in Swift.
Please have a look give proper code

```
extension PeripheralConnectedViewController: CBPeripheralDelegate {
func centralManager(_ central: CBCentralManager, didFailToConnectPeripheral peripheral: CBPeripheral, error: NSError?) {
    if let error = error {
        print("Error connecting peripheral: \(error.localizedDescription)")
    }
}func peripheral(_ peripheral: CBPeripheral, didDiscoverServices error: Error?) {
    if let error = error {
        print("Error discovering services: \(error.localizedDescription)")
    }

    peripheral.services?.forEach({ (service) in
        services.append(service)
        tableView.reloadData()
        peripheral.discoverCharacteristics(nil, for: service)
    })
}func peripheral(_ peripheral: CBPeripheral, didDiscoverCharacteristicsFor service: CBService, error: Error?) {
    if let error = error {
        print("Error discovering service characteristics: \(error.localizedDescription)")
    }

    service.characteristics?.forEach({ characteristic in
        if let descriptors = characteristic.descriptors {
            print(descriptors)
        }

        print(characteristic.properties)
    })
    for newChar: CBCharacteristic in service.characteristics!{

        peripheral.readValue(for: newChar)
         peripheral.setNotifyValue(true, for: newChar)


    }
}
func peripheral(_ peripheral: CBPeripheral, didReadRSSI RSSI: NSNumber, error: Error?) {
    switch RSSI.intValue {
    case -90 ... -60:
        rssiLabel.textColor = .btOrange
        break
    case -200 ... -90:
        rssiLabel.textColor = .btRed
        break
    default:
        rssiLabel.textColor = .btGreen
    }

    rssiLabel.text = "\(RSSI)dB"
}func peripheral(_ peripheral: CBPeripheral, didUpdateValueFor characteristic: CBCharacteristic, error: Error?) {
    if  var enableValue =  Character("?").asciiValue{
        let enablyBytes = NSData(bytes: &enableValue, length: MemoryLayout<UInt8>.size)
        self.peripheral.writeValue(enablyBytes as Data, for: characteristic, type: CBCharacteristicWriteType.withResponse)

    }

    print(characteristic)
}
func peripheral(_ peripheral: CBPeripheral, didUpdateNotificationStateFor characteristic: CBCharacteristic, error: Error?) {

}
```

Comment: What have you tried? What's your code? What did you succeed? What did you fail? Did you find the device? Did you find the services? Did you find the characteristic? Did you find how to interpret the values?

Comment: I need to interpret data from characterstics

Comment: And what does say the documentation? Because developer could have put anything, to utf8 encoded string to hash256 then xored integers... What's the UUID of the characteristics ?

Comment: 65333333-A115-11E2-9E9A-0800200CA101 ,65333333-A115-11E2-9E9A-0800200CA102,65333333-A115-11E2-9E9A-0800200CA103 for one Service

Comment: That's a custom one then. What's the value of `theCharacteristic.value`? What is it supposed to mean? What does say the doc about it? At anytime, you can give information and edit your question with it...

Comment: I am getting nil Value from theCharacteristic.value

Comment: Do you have any source code to retrieve data from BLE Device?

Comment: Are you sure the value is nil? How did you read it? Can you at some point show code, or do I (or other SO user that may want to help you) constantly have to ask you to obtain informations and try to guess what's wrong?

Comment: extension PeripheralConnectedViewController: CBPeripheralDelegate {
 func centralManager(_ central: CBCentralManager, didFailToConnectPeripheral peripheral: CBPeripheral, error: NSError?) {
        if let error = error {
            print("Error connecting peripheral: \(error.localizedDescription)")
        }
 }

Comment: func peripheral(_ peripheral: CBPeripheral, didDiscoverServices error: Error?) {
  if let error = error {
   print("Error discovering services: \(error.localizedDescription)")
  }
  
  peripheral.services?.forEach({ (service) in
   services.append(service)
   tableView.reloadData()
   peripheral.discoverCharacteristics(nil, for: service)
  })
 }

Comment: Could you edit your question with that code and format it? Also, where is the code where you read actually the value of the characteristic?

Comment: In `func peripheral(_ peripheral: CBPeripheral, didUpdateValueFor characteristic: CBCharacteristic, error: Error?)`, what's `characteristic.value` then? Is the method called?