# Retrieve data from a ble device swift

Tags: swift, bluetooth-lowenergy

To retrieve data from a ble device

```
selectedPeripheral.writeValue(newData, for: txCharacteristic, type: .withResponse)
```

got crashed at `txCharacteristic`; when I print `txCharacteristic`, its value is like

```
<CBCharacteristic: 0x280cb8000, UUID = 6E400002-B5A3-F393-E0A9-E50E24DCCA9E, properties       = 0xC, value = (null), notifying = NO>
```

Comment: Join the logs, and your code so we can help you

Comment: What is the crash?  You say that you want to retrieve a value but you are calling `writeValue`

Comment: can anybody help to retrieve value from ble device

Comment: Check this link, maybe that help you 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48077499/how-to-retrieve-data-from-ble-device-in-ios

Answer (score 0):

Try readValue instead:

```
selectedPeripheral.readValue(for: txCharacteristic)
```

When you call this method to read the value of a characteristic descriptor, the peripheral calls the peripheral(_:didUpdateValueFor:error:) method of its delegate object. If the peripheral successfully retrieves the value of the characteristic descriptor, you can access it through the characteristic descriptor’s value property.

source:
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corebluetooth/cbperipheral/1518789-readvalue

Comment: Hi @maor, How I can verify, is the input password is correct?